# wordpress + react + оптимизация под SEO

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, seo

Всем привет, кратко о сути моей проблемы. Блог, бэк в котором wordpress, а на фроте реакт. Посты мобут быть двух категорий: посты и подкасты. Для оторажения этих постов используются разный компонеты: Вот примет роутинга:

`<Route path='/single-podcast/:id' component={SinglePodcast}/>
 <Route path='/archives/:id' component={SingleArticle}/>`

В чём собственно проблема? Проблема в том что из-за того что в в вордпресе не прописанные все эти линки, шаринг в соцсети, который есть на постах и подкастах не коректо работает( google+ говорит что ссылка не дествительна) .

Заказчик хотит чтобы в адресной строке было название статьи а не id.
Аргументирует тем что будет лучше для SEO. Можно ли как-то достучатся до поста по нейму?

И конечно я использую REST API. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Я уже извёлся весь по этому поводу.

Comment: ссылки вида /archives/:title-:id

Answer (score 0):

Можно вытащить поиском. Например, пост "Привет, мир!" с моего тестового сайта доступен по такой ссылке: http://test.kagg.eu/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?search="привет, мир"

Comment: Ну а если два поста с одинаковым названием будет?

Comment: Ну а отчего бы не попробовать? Это же 5 минут. Я попробовал у себя, сделал второй пост с таким же именем. Выводятся оба. Перейдите по ссылке, увидите два поста.

Comment: В этом и проблема, что если я передам в ownProps нейм, а нейм не уникальный то какой мне пост отображать? Вот какой код исползую сейчас, когда вытаскиваю через id:  WP.posts().id( this.props.ownProps.params.id ).then(( post ) => this.setState({post})).

Comment: Это уже логика работы вашего сайта - какой пост отображать. К программированию и WP этот вопрос не относится вообще. Пусть ваш заказчик скажет, какой пост ему отображать.